# Prove that if A is bounded in $ \mathbb{R}$, then $\inf(A) \leq \sup(A)$

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

Can you verify my proof to the statement "If $A$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\inf(A) \leq \sup(A)$"?

Solution:
Since $A$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, there is $0 < B \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\left| A \right| \leq B$ or $-B \leq A \leq B$. Hence, $B$ and $-B$ are upper bound and lower bound of $A$, respectively. By the Completeness Axiom, $b=\sup(A)$ and $-b=\inf(A)$ both exist. Thus, the following also holds
$$\inf(A) =-b \leq A \leq b = \sup(A).$$
Therefore, $\inf(A) \leq \sup(A)$

Comment: What is the meaning of $$\inf(A) =-b \leq A \leq b = \sup(A)$$?

Comment: By definition, for all $x\in A$, $\inf(A)\leq x\leq \sup(A)$...

Comment: Doesn't this hold for any $A\neq\emptyset$ ? Observe that $\sup(A) < \inf(A)$ means that all upper bound on $A$ are strictly less than all lower bounds on $A$, if $a$ is a lower bound and $b$ a upper bound then for all $x\in A$, $a\leq x\leq b < a$ which is false for any $x\in A$, therefore $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: It depens which sense you give to the comparison of $-\infty$ and $\infty$. @P.Quinton

Comment: No, this is not a good proof. If $b=\sup A$, it is not guaranteed that $-b=\inf A$. Just take a set that is not symmetrical to the origin, say: $A=(-1, 2), \sup A=2, \inf A=-1$. Also, I think the problem should specify that $A$ is nonempty, because an empty set is bounded but has no infimum (or alternatively has infimum $+\infty$) and has no supremum (or alternatively has supremum $-\infty$).

Comment: @P.Quinton Well if it holds for any $A$ it certainly holds for bounded $A$. But as you note, the condition needs $A$ being nonempty.